# AppEngine dev_appserver.py not showing any outputs

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I installed Python2.6 and Google App Engine (GAE).

I realized that GAE does not run on 2.6, so I installed 2.5 as well.

Now I have a very basic code as follows and it does not show on the localhost:8080

I typed the following in cmd.exe under my dir testapps.

c:\Users\myname\testapps>"\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" helloworld

I am hoping someone lead me to the right direction.

helloworld/helloworld.py

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

helloworld/app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you try to run dev_appserver?  Can you connect to localhost:8080, and if so, is there a 404 or 500 error message?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you take a look at the guestbook sample program that is included with the SDK. It is located in the demos directory, and I think that looking at the structure of guestbook.py will go a long way towards helping you get a working app.